# Prettier not formatting things correctly

Tags: html, prettier

I used Emmett to give 6 buttons with class btn and content as submit.

btn.btn*6{submit}

emmet worked correctly and gave the below thing as output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2QQg.png)

but when I saved the file prettier is formatting it incorrectly and breaking the button on two lines as below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwBHg.png)

Answer (score 0):

my solution about the case is you can disable prettier extension for a moment and try to save your code with the first picture format (not breaking into two lines). And try to run your project/app. After the program run successfully, you can enable the prettier again. Hope it can help you.

Comment: You can leave this answer as a comment, and summarise these infos into a concise answer